# Flag duplicate question without answer

Tags: discussion, moderation, disputed-flags

Recently I faced one problem: there are two similar questions at SO posted in 2 hours. I watched them and want to flag them as `duplicate`.

It is regarding those questions:

[First question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728902/how-to-express-an-inequality-in-linear-matrix-inequality-format-in-matlab-to-use)

[Second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728180/how-to-express-an-inequality-in-form-of-lmi-in-matlab-and-use-the-feasp-functio)

I think if we will answer one of them, we will answer both.
But I can't mark them using the built-in option in the flag menu called `a duplicate... This question has been asked before and already has an answer.`, as this questions still has no answers!

What to do in this situation?
Can we avoid this duplicates or do we need them?

**EDIT.**
Before I post this question I tried to flag this question I'm talking about as duplicate. But here the answer of moderator:

> duplicate of [stackoverflow.com/questions/33728180/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728180/how-to-express-an-inequality-in-form-of-lmi-in-matlab-and-use-the-feasp-functio) – Mikhail_Sam 2
>   days ago   **declined** - flags should only be used to make moderators
>   aware of content that requires their intervention

**EDIT 2**.
The 2nd question were closed: [you can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728180/how-to-express-an-inequality-in-form-of-lmi-in-matlab-and-use-the-feasp-functio). Irony that I was flagged to close it, my flag was declined but question were closed...

So, now we know what to do. But only one question: How they can flag it as `duplicate... as already HAS A ANSWER`! How they did this? I can't choose this menu because of `This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer` error!

Comment: Wait for one of them to be answered, and then flag the other one.

Comment: FYI: the 2nd question is now closed as a dupe of the 1st

Answer (score 3):

Good spot, the questions appear to be exactly the same. So it's probably a homework question/school assignment on which at least two students got stuck. Either way, somebody can probably help them on their way, but having 2 similar questions up on the site seems pointless, whether they are answered or not.

Exact duplicate questions like this (using exactly the same code) are pretty rare. Normally you'd vote to close the newer of the two questions. But as you say, neither has an answer yet, so you can't do that currently.

In this specific case, I'd use the `Off-topic > Other` close reason on the newest of the two questions. There you can specify a custom reason why you're voting to close that question. This will also post a comment in your name underneath the question stating that reason. So if you link to the other question, other people can see what you're talking about and can choose to vote to close the questions themselves, backing your given reason. If four other people agree with you (which I think shouldn't take too long), the question will be closed and the reason will be put under the question.

This way, there is no need to bug a moderator, because this is an example that can (and should) easily be solved by the community itself.

Comment: _"There you can specify a custom reason why you're voting to close that question."_ Problem with this: With less than 3k rep, the OP _cannot_ use other. Those of us that can only flag get "Blatantly Off-Topic" instead, which doesn't quite fit here. Do you have any different advice to add for those who cannot close vote?

Comment: @Kendra I Just run into this with 3 questions describing the same problem in different ways but actually wanting to know the same answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51692474/ionic-4-android-back-button-not-working Seems like we can only flag for moderator attention and hope it doesn't get declined or grind reputation  until we reach 3k ._.